# Can I replace conjunction with implication here?

Tags: logic

Using a model where the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and one binary predicate $p$ exists, that returns $true$ if its second argument is divisible by the first one, show that each two numbers have a biggest common divisor.

I came up with such an answer:

$\forall_{x}\forall_{y}\exists_{z}((p(z,x)\wedge p(z,y))\Rightarrow\forall_{v}((p(v,x)\wedge p(v,y))\Rightarrow p(v,z)))$

but in the textbook there is a conjunction instead of the first arrow. I can't tell if both answers are correct or not. I know that the two would have different meaning, but I can't figure out if there is something wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a law of *propositional logic* called [Exportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_%28logic%29) :

> $((P \land Q) \rightarrow R) \leftrightarrow (P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R))$.

But $((P \land Q) \land R)$ is **not** equivalent to : $((P \land Q) \rightarrow R)$.

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me if my answer is correct? I understand it is not the same, but there may be more than one possible solution.

Comment: @Kapol - No, they are not the same. You want that $z$ is a number which divides both $x$ and $y$ **and** that for any other divisor of $x$ and $y$, this one is also divisor of $z$ (because $z$ is the "biggest"). Thus, you need **and**.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer evaluates to a true statement also for $p(x,y)\equiv x\ne y$, for example. Or for $p(x,y)\equiv (1<x<y\,\land\, x| y)$ (the first is a proper divisor of the second). But do two numbers really always have a greatest common *proper* divisor?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are changing the way $p$ works. You can't do that.